# import my library in app

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I developed android library and I tried import this library in other app "compileOnly"

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'xxx.xxx.xxx:xx-xx-xx:1.0'
}
```

but gradle show me:

> "Android dependency 'xxx-xxx-xxx:xx-xx-xx:1.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android dependencies (AARs) can provide resources such as drawables and layout files that must be available in the build output. A `compileOnly`/`provided` dependency is not included in the build output, and thus the two are not compatible.