# Android dependency is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1 with the latest Gradle version (https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.8-20180417000132+0000-all.zip).

When I use compileOnly dependencies some of them won't compile, some will.
E.g.

```
compileOnly "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
```

works perfectly while

```
compileOnly "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0"
```

gives a compile error:

```
Android dependency 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported
```

I was under the impression than any dependency can be compileOnly. Nothing indicates otherwise (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations). Both of these libraries have transitive dependencies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would either of those be used `compileOnly`? That says "compile against the library, but do not include the contents in the APK".

Comment: That's just an example. In reality I'd use releaseCompileOnly for the Stetho library. I wanted the example to be as simple as possible.

Comment: another example (a real one) would be: productionCompileOnly 'com.bugsee:bugsee-android:1.11.9' with production being the flavor I'd use for production builds

Comment: Using Gradle 4.4, I get the same error with the `compileOnly "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"` from your question. Given the error message, perhaps the limitation is on AARs. I have used `compileOnly` successfully with AutoValue, but that's a JAR, as that's a pure-Java library.

Comment: I guess that's true even if it's not documented anywhere. Not sure why such an important fact wouldn't be mentioned at all (not here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#configure-dependencies, nor here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Comment: Well, my AAR idea is just a theory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818602/115145) reflects my thinking. In terms of why such a limitation would not be documented... *lots* of things in Android are not documented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an experiment, I created a new Android Studio 3.1.1 project. Then, I added a `lib` module to it as a plain Java library module. I could add `compileOnly project(":lib")` to the app module, and it compiled. I changed the `lib` module to be an Android library module (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) with a minimum manifest, and now `compileOnly project(":lib")` gets the error that you do: "Android dependency 'project :lib' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported".

Since there were no other material changes in the `lib` module, the `compileOnly` limitation is on Android library modules.

My guess is that it is unclear what "compile only" means for manifest entries, resources, assets, etc. So, [they officially punted](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74428302#comment7).

I filed [an issue, requesting documentation of this limitation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78332127). My requests for documentation usually fall on deaf ears.

Answer (score 4):

At the dawn of "Dynamic feature modules", `compileOnly` Android library modules could make sense, to allow easy access to the feature module from the base app when it is installed.

That's why I created this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109894265

Feel free to star it and comment with your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a project with many libraries.

I have a `libX` that I implement in debug with `debugImplementation project(':libX')` to work with sources, but in release build I target published version `releaseImplementation "com.company:libX:1.0.0"`.

After a refactor, I got a similar error during a release sync about my libX.

> Android dependency 'com.company:libX:1.0.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported.

However, I wasn't using any `compileOnly`...

The problem was due to one lib which was using `libX` always as source, (`implementation project(':libX')`). So in release, gradle was confused as it was implementing `libX` as sources in some libs, and as published lib in other.