# Error: Program type already present: androidx.asynclayoutinflater.R

Tags: android, androidx

I've tried upgrading my facebook sdk my app was using to the latest version (5.1.1), and it somehow took me down a rabbit hole of migrating my project to AndroidX. After doing the migration and ironing out some gradle issues, I now have a build issue `Error: Program type already present: androidx.asynclayoutinflater.R`

I've been trying to resolve my problem using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49837806/1219956) and other variants of it but Im finding it difficult to find which libraries are using `androidx.asynclayoutinflater.R`

when i dump out my dependancies i get this

```
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.4.2@aar
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.4.2@aar
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.4.2@jar
+--- androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.codewaves.stickyheadergrid:stickyheadergrid:0.9.6@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3@aar
+--- com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0@aar
+--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:5.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3@aar
+--- androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.1@aar
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0@aar
+--- com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:1.3.1@jar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:18.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0@aar
+--- ca.barrenechea.header-decor:header-decor:0.2.8@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-places:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:5.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.emoji:emoji:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1@aar
+--- com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44@jar
+--- com.appsflyer:segment-android-integration:1.18@aar
+--- com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:mixpanel:2.1.0@jar
+--- com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.4.0-beta1@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0@jar
+--- io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.19.5@aar
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1@jar
+--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar
+--- me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar
+--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1@jar
+--- se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar
+--- androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31@jar
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2@jar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3@jar
+--- com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.10.0@aar
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.8.0@jar
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0@jar
+--- com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.6.2@aar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2@jar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.6@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.7@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.4.1@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar
+--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31@jar
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14@jar
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0@jar
+--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3@jar
+--- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.3@jar
+--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0@jar
\--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0@jar
```

which shows the line `+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar` only once (well once per product flavor/build type)

**update:**
found a more tree like dependency graph, here is a snippet but there is a huge amount of this stuff, cant even paste it on pastebin there is so much

```
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
```

tried removing these which seemed to have no effect

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

my dependencies look like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'ca.barrenechea.header-decor:header-decor:0.2.8'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:segment-android-integration:1.+'
    implementation 'com.codewaves.stickyheadergrid:stickyheadergrid:0.9.6'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:mixpanel:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    //---Testing---
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0'
    //-------------
}
```

I've also tried to force the support library version, not sure if this has any usefulness or if im doing it wrong, but i saw it was suggested in a post here on SO

```
final SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '28.0.0'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    }
}
```

I also have this in my gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Does anyone know an easy way to find what is using this particular dependancy so i can try resolve the duplication, or just know what library might be causing it?

Comment: When you migrate to Android X, don't use support:appcompat. Use androidx.core:core. Try removing them.

Comment: @TheAnkush if i take out that `resolutionStrategy` stuff i am still getting the same error, so nothing is actually using support:appcompat

Comment: Did you migrated manually to Android X or like the screenshot in answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929912/3318025  I faced some compilation error when I migrated manually. You could try the android studio way.

Comment: @TheAnkush yeah i did use android studios migration tool, i have a feeling this is being caused by `android.enableJetifier=true` which says it takes libraries that are using the old support lib and upgrades their dependencies to use androidx stuff, and im assuming its putting in a duplicate somewhere maybe :?

Comment: Yup this the case. Plus I am doubting if   'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' is needed when you have androidx:core:core... ? Also try upgrading core:core to core:core:2.0.0-rc01 ... I would suggest use all latest version you can find in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings

Comment: removing 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' doesnt seem to affect anything, but still same error, i cant seem to use 2.0.0-rc01 either, doesnt find it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after days of suffering I finally found the issue

i had to change

```
implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:1.3.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android.integrations:firebase:1.3.1@aar'
```

fml

The easiest way to trouble shoot this i found was to make a clean new android project and put all your dependencies from your main project in there and use divide and conquer to pin point which library is causing the issue specifically. Found a random 0 rating answer that suggested putting @aar on the end without an explanation, and it worked.

Comment: I had the same problem with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'` and suffixing with `@aar` fixed it. Wtf.

Comment: But then I had a runtime error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800681/cant-depend-on-firebase-ml-kit

Comment: After banging my head against a wall of errors for over a day, this was the fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend a slightly different approach to this common issue. First and foremost: start on a clean slate! That means, File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart, then Build -> Clean Project, followed by Build -> Rebuild Project. Now update all dependencies to latest (although that's a can of worms sometimes as new issues may be introduced). This usually takes care of it for me.

I get this issue from time to time and I find that it happens when switching between branches with some differences in the dependencies. So if you're going back and forth between a service branch (e.g., maintaining production code) and a feature branch (e.g., introducing newer dependencies, either in terms of name or simply version), you're going to run into this. Android Studio does a terrible job at (many things but especially) cleaning up when switching branches. It's looking at outdated cached information and it finds conflicts that are not really there.

I hope this helps!